# Roboelectric assertion fails with shared preferences android

Tags: android, junit4, robolectric

Referring this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748417/providing-test-data-for-sharedpreferences-for-robolectric), I  tried to save shared preferences, but my assertion fails.

This is my test class

```
@Test
public void testSharedPreferences(){
activity=actController.create().get();
 loginButton=(Button)activity.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
 userName=(EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.userName);
 userPassword=(EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.userPassword);
 sharedPrefs =    ShadowPreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Robolectric.application.getApplicationContext());
 sharedPrefs.edit().putString("userName", "user1").commit();

 assertThat(userName.getText().toString(),equalTo("user1"));

}
```

This is the code in the class under test-

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
private EditText userName,userPassword;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
         final SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
         String name = sharedPreferences.getString("userName", "");
         if (!"".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            userName.setText(name);
        }
}
```

`Assertion` fails and it says expected `"user1"` but found `""`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test is creating the activity first (and triggering `onCreate()` too early), so your changes to the SharedPrefs have no effect. Try this instead:

```
@Test
public void testSharedPreferences() {
     // First set up the shared prefs
     sharedPrefs = ShadowPreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Robolectric.application.getApplicationContext());
     sharedPrefs.edit().putString("userName", "user1").commit();

     // Create the activity - this will call onCreate()
     activity=actController.create().get();
     loginButton=(Button)activity.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
     userName=(EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.userName);
     userPassword=(EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.userPassword);

     // Verify text
     assertThat(userName.getText().toString(),equalTo("user1"));

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just got to do this now and saw someone answered :).