# Mocking SharedPreferences.Editor.putString()

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I recently started coding my really first android project using Android Studio 3.1.2 and SDK 19.

I'm writing unit tests for my components at the moment and use Mockito for mocking android API dependant objects. When I wrote the test for my `SessionHandler`, a helper class, that manages data stored in `SharedPreferences` I came across the problem, that, if I want to check, if e. g. `mockEdit.remove("my_key")` was successful, I didn't know, how  to mock the behavior in particular.

This is how I prepare my mocking stuff:

```
private final Context mockedContext = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
private final SharedPreferences mockedPrefs = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences.class);
private final SharedPreferences.Editor mockEdit = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences.Editor.class);
private boolean shouldReturnTestUUID = true;

@Before
public void prepareMocks() {
    Mockito.when(mockedContext.getSharedPreferences(anyString(), anyInt()).thenReturn(mockedPrefs);
    Mockito.when(mockedPrefs.getString("my_key", null)).thenReturn(shouldReturnTestUUID ? "test_UUID" : null);
    //this is the one, I got stuck at
    Mockito.when(mockEdit.remove("my_key")).thenReturn(mockEdit.putString("my_key", null));
}
```

The method i'm actually testing:

```
public synchronized static void removeAppInstanceID(Context context) {
    if (appInstanceID != null) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("session", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPrefs.edit().remove("my_key").apply();
    }
}
```

The test method:

```
@Test
public void canRemoveUUID() {
    shouldReturnTestUUID = false;
    SessionHandler.removeAppInstanceID(mockedContext);
    assertNull(mockedPreferences.getString("my_key", null));
    shouldReturnTestUUID = true;
}
```

If I try to run this test I get an UnfinishedStubbingException referring to the line where I want to mock `mockEdit.remove("my_key")`. Seemingly, the stub doesn't know what to do with `mockEdit.putString("my_key", null);`.

So my question is, how to mock this method, so I can call `mockedPrefs.getString("my_key")` and check if the returned value is `null`? Thanks in forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a unit test (without integration with Android Framework) would be enough. You could only test that the `remove()` and `apply()` methods are called.

For that you need to determine the editor (a mock in this case) returned by `edit()` method

A Kotlin example, using Mockito, below...

```
@Test
public void canRemoveUUID() {
    // Arrange
    val mockEdit = mock(SharedPreferences.Editor::class.java)
    `when`(mockEdit.remove("my_key"))
        .thenReturn(mockEdit)

    val mockedPrefs = mock(SharedPreferences::class.java)
    `when`(mockedPrefs.edit())
        .thenReturn(mockEdit)

    val mockedContext = mock(Context::class.java)
    `when`(mockedContext.getSharedPreferences("session", Context.MODE_PRIVATE))
        .thenReturn(mockedPrefs)


    // Act  
    SessionHandler.removeAppInstanceID(mockedContext);

    // Assert
    verify(mockEdit, times(1)).remove("my_key")
    verify(mockEdit, times(1)).commit()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- Mock `SharedPreferences` using [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) like here:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9755286/1150795. Robolectric is a common
  tool for unit testing Android applications and Mocking objects from
  Android SDK
- You can add additional layer of abstraction and hide
  saving `SharedPreferences` behind an interface, which can be mocked with Mockito

Comment: How do I add a layer to hide save SharedPreferences in particular?

Comment: You can create additional interface exposing methods like `putString(...)`, `getString(...`), etc., add its implementation containing direct usage of `SharedPreferences`, which will be used in the app, Mock this interface in unit tests and verify with Mockito that particular methods (`putString(...)`, `getString(...)`, etc.) were called. Nevertheless, Robolectric may be the easiest approach and you may need it during testing your Android app anyway (e.g. to Mock Android `Context` and other Android related stuff).